# HTTP 500 error That’s odd... the website can’t display this page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have just changed the php.ini file for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.Now when i upload an image with size=5M it will display the following error.

> HTTP 500 error
>   That’s odd... the website can’t display this page
>   The site may be under maintenance or could have a programming error.

But when i upload an image with small size it will generate no error and the image upload successfully.

How can i fix this problem???

Comment: add more `RAM` ...

Comment: really, i have 8gb RAM in my laptop

Comment: i think it's enough RAM. Any other reason that can generate this error????

Comment: There are two php.ini files. One for CLI and one for web server (i.e. Apache). Which one are you changing? When making the change did you restart your web server?

Comment: I have change both of php.ini files

Comment: yes, I had restarted the xampp

Comment: Please check the apache error log and also the laravel.log

Comment: add `phpinfo();` as the second line of `public/index.php`, go to you site, check the `upload_max_filesize` from that page. If those are not the values you have added. check the php.ini location from that page

Comment: I have checked the 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size' in phpinfo() it changed successfully.

Comment: Did you restart your server? Also, what is your `memory_limit` set to?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should first check the error generated by apache/nginx :

Run `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` or `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` depending on the one you have in one terminal and keep it open

Then go to browser and do the actions again which are giving you 500 error. once error occurs, you would see it tailed in the error file in the terminal window.

2. Check if `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are updated in php.ini of the web user and not cli. You can do `phpinfo()` and check in browser if the values are reflected correctly. If you are using xamp then check `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log` path or use `logs` button in the application GUI to see. This step will be the deciding factor for whats the error about.
3. Even if you have increased the above parameters, server might take some time to process large file, and exceed `max_execution_time`. You can check if thats the case, which can be found depending on the error you have seen in step 1.
4. Restart your apache2 server and also any additional caching mechanism enabled like `opcache` for example.
5. There are 2 more parameters which can affect which are `max_input_time` and `memory_limit`. I would not suggest increasing these unless thats where error is occurring, specially having too large value in `memory_limit`.

Hops this helps.